# Validation CSS 3.0 not a known property name

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, visual-studio, validation

I have multiple CSS pages and every CSS property gets the following warning:

> Validation(CSS 3.0): "`[]`" is not a known property name.

I can run my code, that's not the problem as it's only a warning.

It wouldn't bother me if my code asked *what properties are possible to use?* I've searched for 2 days now and also reinstalled my VS2015. My colleague doesn't have that problem on the same program.

Any suggestions about what could be wrong?

A bit Code (everything is green underlined):

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #CCC;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #CCC;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0px !important;
    top:  0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.menu {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #333;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 320px;
    height:100%;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0px !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}
```

Hope thats clear enough ;)

Comment: Can you show any code where you set the attribute?

Comment: hope thats what you wanted

Comment: On which line does it give you the validation error?

Comment: every line in every css file , all, not one singl line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) solved the problem.

Comment: How do you mean? This answer does not help a newbie to VS

Answer (score 4):

In case people are still searching for an answer to this puzzling issue, I found restarting visual studio resolved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

In visula studio CSS version would have selected to CSS3.0 change it to older the problem will be solved. 
[image]

Comment: yeah i searched for that funktion but couldn´t find it anywhere

Comment: i can change teh html validation and it should be done but nothing changes

Comment: is styles are working perfectly when it renders to browser ?

Comment: Then just move your styles to a css file and then edit from there you will be able to see the version selector then !

Comment: well they are in a css file :D

Comment: please go through below link https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/805848/css-editor-context-menu-missing-build-style-option

Comment: that works for a few thing but its not a long time solution for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I only see the warnings when one of my .htm resource files are opened. The read-only mode (purple window) when selecting the file from the Solution Explorer also counts as opened.

If I close the file then the warnings disappear. This is definitely not solving the problem there seem to be here, but it should stop bothering you with the warnings, which was good enough for me as the file would display as expected.